# check if the latitude and longitude lie in the range of my google map start and end destination

Tags: php, android, location, maps

I am retrieving the latitude and longitudes from the database and want to check if those lie on my route(found from google direction API)

I was thinking of using geofencing but I want to show a marker of the latitude and longitude on my route only

Comment: What is the issue? Which code r u using?

Comment: i am using android(java)

Comment: Means are you using any lib? You can give radius for your range

Comment: but the radius may show the markers of  latitudes and longitudes  of other routes as well when the radius is large for longer routes, when i am retrieving latitudes and longitudes from php i want to show a marker on the latitude and longitude which lies only on my route.

Comment: You want to route between two points center of map? No other marker should not be shown?

Comment: i think she want to find location received from server are on polyline(route) or not ? am i right @amishasahu

Comment: ya @akshay_shahane

Answer (score 0):

> you can use [maputils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) by google

```
    if (PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(latLng, rectLine.getPoints()  , false, 500 )) {

 // location in on route

                                        }
```

1. rectline = your ployline
2. 500 tolerence in meter you can set as per your neeed
3. false = flag to tell method if you have used geodesc true
       while plotting polyline

Comment: if there is a huge amount of latitude and longitudes placed in the database . This will take time i guess.

Comment: yes but this is the only way . give it a try this wont make network call to check if location on route it worked for me .

Comment: thanks this worked for me as well but it will result in huge match calculations if you find any better solution please share

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this without huge calculations. Run the calculations in a thread to reduce load on UI thread. if you want to reduce calculations, then maybe you can take every 5th or 10th lat,long from the polyline location list and get distance to your marker using `android.location.Location.distanceBetween()` and then check if its near it.